WPF WebBrowser Control LoadCompleted Event not fired
I'm trying to navigate with WPF WebBrowser Control and to get the Document once loaded.
The Navigated Event is correctly fired (but Document is still not complete)
But the LoadCompleted Event is never fired...
I'm trying this on this swiss URL https://prestations.vd.ch/pub/actiscamac/101091
But I get the same behavior on https://www.google.com
Here is my simple code:
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;

namespace AvisServicesCrawler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic fot MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private static readonly string url = @"https://prestations.vd.ch/pub/actiscamac/101091"; // @"https://www.google.com";
        private static readonly WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Register an event handler for the browser.Navigated event fired when browser has navigated to a new document and has begun loading it.
            browser.Navigated += browserNavigated;
            // Register an event handler for the browser.LoadCompleted event fir ed when document is loaded.
            browser.LoadCompleted += browserLoadCompleted;
        }

        private void goNavigateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Navigate to the desired URL: 
            browser.Navigate(url);
        }
        private void browserNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            mshtml.HTMLDocument document = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)browser.Document;
        }

        private void browserLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            mshtml.HTMLDocument document = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)browser.Document;
        }
    }
}


Remove the static browser field and add the WebBrowser to your XAML markup:


Then you should get a LoadCompleted event after your have ignored the script errors on the page.
There is no reason to use a WebBrowser if you don't indend to display the web page in your application. If you only want to parse the response, then use a HttpClient or similar.
Also note that the WebBrowser control has effectively been replaced by the WebView2 control when it comes to embed modern web content in native Windows applications.
